# Unable to connect the Database and Handle the POST request

Tags: php, html, database

Hello I am working with a predefined template and I am trying to fetch some data from the input space in form of POST/GET request using php. But I am unable to do so, How can I integrate the database and handle the php parameters?

```
<div class="w3_agileits_card_number_grids">
     <div class="w3_agileits_card_number_grid_left">
        <div class="controls">
           <input type="text" placeholder="Adhaar" name="Adhaar" required="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Town/City" name="city" required="">
    <?php 
    if(isset($_GET['Adhaar']) && $_GET ['Adhaar']!=NULL)
    {
       $x = $_GET['Adhaar'];
        echo "Your Adhaar is $x";
    ?>
    }
```

Comment: You have a typo in your code. Noticed it when I was fixing it. It reads `?>` then `}`

Comment: @SuperKevin Doesn't work tried fixing it

Comment: PHP runs on the server. That means you need to process / submit the page in order for PHP to read data from your inputs.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: So You mean on page load you want to fetch data from database and display on this page?

Comment: Or you want to process this page and post the data to database?

Answer (score 1):

```
Hello change your code to this

    <div class="w3_agileits_card_number_grids">
        <div class="w3_agileits_card_number_grid_left">
            <div class="controls">
             <input type="text" placeholder="Adhaar" name="Adhaar" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="controls">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Town/City" name="city" required="">
             <?php 
                  if(isset($_GET['Adhaar']) && $_GET ['Adhaar']!=NULL)
                            {
                              $x = $_GET['Adhaar'];
                              echo "Your Adhaar is $x";
                              //Connect to the database here

                            }
             ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the database connection it depends on which database you are working with but you can start here. A simple Google query with provide you what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

I put together an example for you that may come in handy. This shows how you can use PHP to submit a form print some values that the user enters on the page. I also included some commented out code that you can copy and move to a seperate script and call by changing the `action` value to the file path.

[image]

The PHP script:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        // try {

        // Connect to the database:
        // $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database','port');
        // Retrieve all records:
        // $sql = 'SELECT * FROM categories';
        // $result = $db->query($sql);

        // } catch (Exception $e) {
        // $error = $e->getMessage();
        // }

        // echo '<pre>';
        // Pass MYSQLI_BOTH or MYSQLI_ASSOC as the argument to change the array type
        // $all = $result->fetch_all();
        // echo json_encode($all);
        // echo '</pre>';
        // $db->close();

        $data = [
            "BOB" => "AWESOME",
            "JOE" => "AVERAGE",
            "TOM" => "COOL"
        ];
    }
?>
```

Next, we have the form. I added this form because you need it to submit to the page. (Well you don't "need" it but it makes life easy.)

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">

        <div class="form-group">
           <input class="form-control"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Adhaar"
                  name="adhaar"
                  required
                  value="<?= isset($_POST['adhaar']) ? $_POST['adhaar'] : '' ?>">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control"
                   type="text"
                   placeholder="Town/City"
                   name="city"
                   required
                   value="<?= isset($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : '' ?>">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">CLICK ME!</button>
        </div>

    </form>
    <?php if (isset($_POST['adhaar'])) : ?>
        <p>Hi there <?= $_POST['adhaar'] ?></p>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if (isset($_POST['city'])) : ?>
        <p><?= $_POST['city'] ?> is a great place to live!</p>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if (isset($data)) : ?>
        <?php foreach ($data as $key => $value) : ?>
            <p><?= $key ?> - <?= $value ?></p>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php endif ?>
</div>
```

Last piece of the file simply outputs information onto the page if it finds it in the $_POST global array.

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['adhaar'])) : ?>
    <p>Hi there <?= $_POST['adhaar'] ?></p>
<?php endif ?>

<?php if (isset($_POST['city'])) : ?>
    <p><?= $_POST['city'] ?> is a great place to live!</p>
<?php endif ?>

<?php if (isset($data)) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($data as $key => $value) : ?>
        <p><?= $key ?> - <?= $value ?></p>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

This commented out part here you can use to pull data from the database and pass it back to your page. If you are just starting it's cool to tinker but ideally you DO NOT want to make calls to the db on the same page as your view. It should live in it's own file.

```
        // try {

        // Connect to the database:
        // $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database','port');
        // Retrieve all records:
        // $sql = 'SELECT * FROM categories';
        // $result = $db->query($sql);

        // } catch (Exception $e) {
        // $error = $e->getMessage();
        // }

        // echo '<pre>';
        // Pass MYSQLI_BOTH or MYSQLI_ASSOC as the argument to change the array type
        // $all = $result->fetch_all();
        // echo json_encode($all);
        // echo '</pre>';
        // $db->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should Try This Code ..This is working i Simply add a submit button to it

```
<div class="w3_agileits_card_number_grids">
        <div class="w3_agileits_card_number_grid_left">
            <div class="controls">
            <form method="GET" action="xxx.php">
             <input type="text" placeholder="Adhaar" name="Adhaar" required="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="controls">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Town/City" name="city" required="" />
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="show">
             <?php 
                  if(isset($_GET['submit']) && $_GET ['Adhaar']!=NULL)
                            {
                              $x = $_GET['Adhaar'];
                              echo "Your Adhaar is $x";
                              //Connect to the database here

                            }
             ?>

    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```